# PHP Undefined Index When Decoding From Json

Tags: php, json, indexing, undefined, decode

I am trying to Json decode something and get the value I want.
But I get PHP undefined index error.
This is my code.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"totalGamesPlayed":25,"championId":0}]';
$data = json_decode($json,true); 

$games = $data['totalGamesPlayed'];
echo $games;
?>
```

The problem is the "[" "]" are messing with my code...
I am using an API to get some values.
What I get is this : http://pastebin.com/XrqkAbJf
I need the totalGamesPlayed,the champion ID's except zero (82,106 and 24)
and the TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON and TOTAL_SESSIONS_LOST for these ID's...
For a start, let's find out how can I bypass the "[" and "]" symbols,and then things may be easier..
Thank you in advance!

Comment: When in doubt, `print_r($data)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access your code like this

```
$games = $data[0]['totalGamesPlayed'];
```

Code for getting other info

```
<?php

$json = 'PUT YOUR EXAMPLE JSON HERE';
$data = json_decode($json,true); 

$seasonWon = 0;
$seasonPlayed = 0;
foreach($data as $stats) {
    if($stats['championId'] != 0) {
        echo '<br><br>Total Games Played:'. $stats['totalGamesPlayed'];    
        echo '<br>champion Ids :'.$stats['championId'];
        foreach($stats['stats'] as $stat) {
            if($stat['statType'] == 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON') {
                $seasonWon = $stat['value'];
                echo '<br>TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON :'.$seasonWon;
            }

            if($stat['statType'] == 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_LOST')
            echo '<br>TOTAL_SESSIONS_LOST :'.$stat['value'];

            if($stat['statType'] == 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED') {                
                $seasonPlayed = $stat['value'];
                echo '<br>TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED :'.$seasonPlayed;                
            }
        }
        echo '<br>Games Ratio(TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON / TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED): ('. $seasonWon.'/'.$seasonPlayed.'):'. ($seasonWon/$seasonPlayed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how can I get the ID's and the Sessions Won for them ? :/

Comment: I am struggling with this for over 4 hours and you do it in 10 minutes...Bless you! :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't understand what chmpIds ^.=^ $stat['championId']^ .',  '^; 
the ^-^ things are for... What is ".=" ?
And what is " .', ' "

Comment: And Champion ID's don't show... I get "champion Ids :"
and then blank while It should have been "champion Ids : 82,106,24" right ?

Comment: in your example there are no champion ids which has non zero values

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XrqkAbJf
Scroll down and check mate..There are...82,106 and 24... :(
Not showing :(((

Comment: Thank you ! Worked Like a Charm..if I wanted to get a Win Ratio,How could I divide the wins with the total games played ? Cause I get the true value,along with 20 others :(

Comment: oOkay!Can you tell me how can I get the Win/total games ratio ? :)

Comment: So you want result for TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON/TOTAL_SESSIONS_PLAYED for each individual player.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
$games = $data[0]['totalGamesPlayed'];
```

The problem is your json is an array with it first element is an object

Answer (score 1):

In case of problems like yours, it's handy to peek what your decode data really looks like. So instead of blindly reading, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to look. `print_r($data);` would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [totalGamesPlayed] => 25
            [championId] => 0
        )
)
```

therefore the correct "path" is:

```
$games = $data[0]['totalGamesPlayed'];
```

This is so, because your JSON object is **array** (first and last character of JSON is `[` and `]`) with object as array node (`{`/`}`) and your real values are members of that object. You can **fix** that by checking why you construct JSON that way in the first place (maybe code allows more elements of array), or "extract" object to get rid of being forced to use `[0]` in references:

```
$data = $data[0];
$games = $data['totalGamesPlayed'];
```

and `print_r($data)` would give:

```
Array
(
    [totalGamesPlayed] => 25
    [championId] => 0
)
```

and your former code will start to work:

```
$games = $data['totalGamesPlayed'];
echo $games;
```

gives

```
25
```